# Can there be "spurious" achievements?

Tags: discussion, top-bar, achievements-dialog

Just happend to me: the achievements box showed me a green +1. I was surprised to see that; wondering how "+1" could come up in the first place.

So I clicked on achievements ... the green +1 goes away ... and I am looking at the very same achievements (and "total sum") that I saw there like 30 minutes ago, when I last checked. No signs whatsoever pointing out what that "+1" was about.

Any idea what could be going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably downvoted an answer, which costs you 1 reputation. The answer was then removed, giving you 1 reputation back.

Answer (score 4):

Presumably an answer you downvoted was removed. Therefore the reputation is refunded as it never happened. This "as it never happened" is quite common when it comes to reputation and makes it often hard to diagnose what actually happened.

The reputation tab in your profile should shown what went down since that should show the full history.